# Confused about what constant to use

Tags: android, sip

I just want that my SIP application detects if the other peer has answered my outgoing call, if yes, i want to make write some code(like vibrating the phone or something like this).
I verified the documentation and i find [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipSession.State.html). I don't know what constants should i use and where to put it(normally in the `onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call)`function ?.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc says that `onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call)` is called right after the session has been established so the peer has answered the call by that time ( and 200OK, ACK went through ). So you can hang your "vibrate" or whatever code right on that callback. Also the state that the `call` object should be in is  `IN_CALL`.
If you don't want to process the call establishment but rather just a peer pressing "Answer" button (that does not guarantee that the call will be established since there might be loss of 200OK or ACK message, codec incompatibility or failure to bring up media streams due to NAT or some other networking problems) then I guess you will have to override `onChanged(SipAudioCall call)` and check the state for `INCOMING_CALL_ANSWERING`.

Cheers

Comment: well, it's a little complicated. i'll re-read and re-read it ;). Thanks.